# how to close mobile navigation menu on click outside sidenav menu

Tags: javascript

this is my js to open and close sidenav with id="mySidenav".

```
 function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

How to close the sidenav on clicking outside the sidenav and also when screen size is >600px?

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)